# Adapting a document to tglat2e style and its conflicts with amsthm and caption

Tags: captions, amsthm, journal-publishing, journal, proof-package

I am trying to adapt my document to the `tglat2e`-style of [this journal](https://www.springer.com/mathematics/algebra/journal/31). Please take a look at this MWE:

```
\documentclass{tglat2e}

\let\proof\relax
\let\endproof\relax
%This trick is due to David Carlisle's answer to question number 43835. It fixes some issues.
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{caption}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\begin{document}

\title{Example}

\authors{Mr.~No
\address Department of Mathematics
\email email}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{proof}
Proof.

\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma]
\[
E=mc^2\qedhere
\]
%The \qedhere command does not work at all.
\end{proof}

The qed appears because it is called. With the fix, it appears now twice.\qed
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}

Here is a proof. But the qed-symbol does not occur automatically.
\end{proof}

\begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \caption{This is a caption which\\
    goes over two lines.}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

- This document compiles and throws four errors and one warning. The errors are all related to the presents of `amsthm` which seemingly conflicts the journal style. The obvious suggestion would be: Do not load `amsthm`! But this gives around 500 errors and warnings in my original document. How can I get rid of these errors?
- The warning is related to the `caption`-package. I only need this package for a caption which has a linebreak as in the example. How can I achieve this effect?
- **This issue has been fixed. The fix also resolves one of the errors in the first item.** The proof environment does not work as I am used to. It does not produce qed-symbols automatically but only once called. Further, `\qedhere` does not work at all.

I would be really glad if you could help me with this. Thank you!

**The remaining errors and warnings follow for your reference:**

```
LaTeX Error: Command \theoremstyle already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.57 }

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

 LaTeX Error: Command \newtheoremstyle already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.263 }

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

 LaTeX Error: Command \openbox already defined.

Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.417   \vrule\hfil}}

Your command was ignored.
Type  I <command> <return>  to replace it with another command,
or  <return>  to continue without it.

Package caption Warning: Unsupported document class (or package) detected, usage of the caption package is not recommended. See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tglat2e.cls` incorporates a large part of `amsthm.sty`, but removes any reference to QED symbols.

It's not difficult to restore it, by pasting the relevant macros.

```latex
\documentclass{tglat2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%\usepackage{caption}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}[theorem]{Example}

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{remark}[theorem]{Remark}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\qed}{%
  \ifmmode \mathqed
  \else
    \leavevmode\unskip\penalty9999 \hbox{}\nobreak\hfill
    \quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}%
  \fi
}
\let\QED@stack\@empty
\let\qed@elt\relax
\newcommand{\pushQED}[1]{%
  \toks@{\qed@elt{#1}}\@temptokena\expandafter{\QED@stack}%
  \xdef\QED@stack{\the\toks@\the\@temptokena}%
}
\newcommand{\popQED}{%
  \begingroup\let\qed@elt\popQED@elt \QED@stack\relax\relax\endgroup
}
\def\popQED@elt#1#2\relax{#1\gdef\QED@stack{#2}}
\newcommand{\qedhere}{%
  \begingroup \let\mathqed\math@qedhere
    \let\qed@elt\setQED@elt \QED@stack\relax\relax \endgroup
}
\renewenvironment{proof}[1][\proofname]{\par
  \pushQED{\qed}%
  \normalfont \topsep6\p@\@plus6\p@\relax
  \trivlist
  \item[\hskip\labelsep
        \itshape
    #1\@addpunct{.}]\ignorespaces
}{%
  \popQED\endtrivlist\@endpefalse
}
\def\setQED@elt#1#2\relax{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else \iffirstchoice@ \gdef\QED@stack{\qed@elt{}#2}\fi
  \fi
  #1%
}
\def\qed@warning{%
  \PackageWarning{amsthm}{The \@nx\qedhere command may not work
    correctly here}%
}
\newcommand{\mathqed}{\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}}
\def\linebox@qed{\hfil\hbox{\qedsymbol}\hfilneg}
\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
  \def\math@qedhere{%
    \@ifundefined{\@currenvir @qed}{%
      \qed@warning\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}%
    }{%
      \@xp\aftergroup\csname\@currenvir @qed\endcsname
    }%
  }
  \def\displaymath@qed{%
    \relax
    \ifmmode
      \ifinner \aftergroup\linebox@qed
      \else
        \eqno
        \let\eqno\relax \let\leqno\relax \let\veqno\relax
        \hbox{\qedsymbol}%
      \fi
    \else
       \aftergroup\linebox@qed
    \fi
  }
  \@xp\let\csname equation*@qed\endcsname\displaymath@qed
  \def\equation@qed{%
    \iftagsleft@
      \hbox{\phantom{\quad\qedsymbol}}%
      \gdef\alt@tag{%
        \rlap{\hbox to\displaywidth{\hfil\qedsymbol}}%
        \global\let\alt@tag\@empty
      }%
    \else
      \gdef\alt@tag{%
        \global\let\alt@tag\@empty
        \vtop{\ialign{\hfil####\cr
                \tagform@\theequation\cr
                \qedsymbol\cr}}%
        \setbox\z@
      }%
    \fi
  }
  \def\qed@tag{%
    \global\tag@true \nonumber
    &\omit\setboxz@h {\strut@ \qedsymbol}\tagsleft@false
    \place@tag@gather
    \kern-\tabskip
    \ifst@rred \else \global\@eqnswtrue \fi \global\advance\row@\@ne \cr
  }
  \def\split@qed{%
    \def\endsplit{\crcr\egroup \egroup \ctagsplit@false \rendsplit@
      \aftergroup\align@qed
    }%
  }
  \def\align@qed{%
    \ifmeasuring@ \tag*{\qedsymbol}%
    \else \let\math@cr@@@\qed@tag
    \fi
  }
  \@xp\let\csname align*@qed\endcsname\align@qed
  \@xp\let\csname gather*@qed\endcsname\align@qed
%% Needs some patching up for amsmath 1.2
}{% end of amsmath branch, start plain LaTeX branch
  \def\math@qedhere{%
    \@ifundefined{\@currenvir @qed}{%
      \qed@warning \aftergroup\displaymath@qed
    }{%
      \@xp\aftergroup\csname\@currenvir @qed\endcsname
    }%
  }
  \def\displaymath@qed{%
    \relax
    \ifmmode
      \ifinner \aftergroup\aftergroup\aftergroup\linebox@qed
      \else
        \eqno \def\@badmath{$$}%
        \let\eqno\relax \let\leqno\relax \let\veqno\relax
        \hbox{\qedsymbol}%
      \fi
    \else
       \aftergroup\linebox@qed
    \fi
  }
  \@ifundefined{ver@leqno.clo}{%
    \def\equation@qed{\displaymath@qed \quad}%
  }{%
    \def\equation@qed{\displaymath@qed}%
  }
    \def\@tempa#1$#2#3\@nil#4{%
        \def#4{#1$#2\def\@currenvir{displaymath}#3}%
    }%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname[ \endcsname\relax
        \expandafter\@tempa\[\@nil\[%
    \else
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@tempa\csname[
        \expandafter\endcsname\expandafter\@nil
        \csname[ \endcsname
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\title{Example}

\authors{Mr.~No
\address Department of Mathematics
\email email}

\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Abstract
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{proof}
Proof.

\begin{proof}[Proof of Lemma]
\begin{equation*}
E=mc^2\qedhere
\end{equation*}
%The \qedhere command does not work at all.
\end{proof}

The qed appears because it is called. With the fix, it appears now twice.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}

Here is a proof. But the qed-symbol does not occur automatically.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

You *can't* use the `caption` package, nor you can manually split a caption over two lines, unless you make one of those lines longer than `\@maxcaptionwd`.

```latex
\caption[This is a caption]{\makebox[\csname @maxcaptionwd\endcsname][l]{This is a caption which}\\
          goes over two lines.}
```

The optional argument is obviously necessary.

***Note*** You risk rejection of your manuscript.

Comment: Thanks for looking into the issue. If I understand you correctly, you suggest not to load `amsthm`  at all and just paste some into the preamble. But for `\qedhere` that does not work because it is still not defined. (All this is not overimportant. The copy editor will change things maybe anyway, but I want to communicate what kind of layout and format I intend.)

Comment: I looked into the `amsthm` package by downloading it from `ctan`. It is not clear to me where you took that code from (and how to expand it to cover `\qedhere`) as there is no file called `amsthm.sty` in the `zip` folder. I personally don't see the danger of just accepting/ignoring the warning of the `caption` package, but maybe there is some, and unwanted effects can occur.

Comment: @user66288 You just copy the code in my answer.

Comment: I am so sorry, I think I missed some of the code in your answer and copied it only partially. That was my fault.

Comment: As a warning for others: I want to note that the `tglat2e` style is also not compatible with `cleveref`. You cannot do other than to unload this package in case you use it, otherwise 500 errors and warnings pop up. Although I pasted the code of egreg into the file, the `\qedhere` command did still not work correctly as you expect from a regular setup (`amsart` class, for example) but the warnings and errors referenced in my question disappeared. It produced a tomerstone now put positioned it always wrongly (at least in my complete file).